# Torii session does not persist after refresh

Tags: session, ember.js, ember-cli, emberfire, torii

Currently, my Ember-cli application logs out after refresh. I have altered my code a lot to try to get it to work, but none helped. If necessary, I will try to implement authentication with another provider.

I have a route for application, which is just the logout and a route for login, which deals with login, because the client wants to style it.

My config/environment.js file looks like this:

```
firebase: 'https://<my-website-here>.firebaseio.com/',
    torii: {
      sessionServiceName: 'session'
    },
```

app/adapters/application.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import FirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/adapters/firebase';

const { inject } = Ember;

export default FirebaseAdapter.extend({
  firebase: inject.service(),
});
```

app/torii-adapters/application.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ToriiFirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/torii-adapters/firebase';

export default ToriiFirebaseAdapter.extend({
  firebase: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

app/routes/application.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
 actions: {
   logout: function() {
       this.get('session').close().then(function() {
           this.transitionTo('application');
       }.bind(this));
   }
  }
});
```

app/routes/login.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    login: function() {
      var controller = this.get('controller');
      var email = controller.get('userEmail');
      var password = controller.get('userPassword');
        this.get('session').open('firebase', {
             provider: 'password',
             email: email,
             password: password
        }).then(function() {
            this.transitionTo('dashboard');
        }.bind(this));
    }
  }
});
```

Yeah, currently, login and logout works just fine, but I cannot refresh the page in the middle of the session, or else it logs out me automatically.

Thanks to anyone in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Torii does not persist your authentication session for you. You need to implement this yourself in the `open`, `fetch`, and `close` hooks of your adapter.

The easiest way to do this is with [the localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

#### Fetch

In the `fetch` hook, you need to pull your session data out of localStorage. If there's nothing there, either throw an exception or return a promise which will `reject`.

#### Open

Your adapter needs to `resolve` with the session data, but should also store it in localStorage for later sessions.

#### Close

Clear the localStorage key for your session data and return a promise which will `resolve`.

#### Example

[Here's the application adapter from one of my applications](https://github.com/alisdair/team-time-zone/blob/master/app/torii-adapters/application.js), which uses the Slack API with Torii. The `open` hook is likely different from what you need for Firebase, but hopefully this gives you something to work with.

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
  storage: Ember.inject.service(),

  fetch() {
    let token = this.get('storage.token');

    if (Ember.isEmpty(token)) {
      throw new Error('No token in storage');
    }

    return Ember.RSVP.resolve({ token });
  },

  open(authentication) {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Ember.$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/tokens',
        data: authentication,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: Ember.run.bind(null, resolve),
        failure: Ember.run.bind(null, reject)
      });
    }).then(data => {
      let token = data.accessToken;

      this.set('storage.token', token);

      return { token };
    });
  },

  close() {
    this.set('storage.token', null);

    return Ember.RSVP.resolve();
  }
});
```

[My `storage` service is a wrapper around the browser localStorage API](https://github.com/alisdair/team-time-zone/blob/master/app/services/storage.js).

Comment: Thank you, this definitely put me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much easier way.

app/routes/application.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    return this.get('session').fetch().catch(function() {});
  },

  model() {
    if(this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
      return this.store.findAll('post');
    } else {
      this.transitionTo('login');
  }
});
```

The key is the `beforeModel` fetching the session.

I found this little nugget here: https://blog.isnorcreative.com/2016/07/30/ember-firebase.html